# Model name appearing in my validation error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still struggling to get my validation error message to display without the name of the model appearing in it, I have a nested model called `AnimalImage` and am performing a validation on whether a file has been submitted.

```
def limit_num_of_images
  if image.size < 1
    errors.add(:base, "Please add an image")
     ap(errors.inspect)
  end
end
```

The error I get in this instance is:

```
Animal images base Please add an image
```

All I want to show is:

```
Please add an image
```

Looking in the console the output of errors.inspect is

```
"#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fa0192d1890 @base=#<AnimalImage id: nil, animal_id: nil, image: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:base=>[\"Please add an image\"]}>"
```

So the messages are in a hash? if that's the case I need to find a way of not displaying the key?

Finally in my view I am outputting the error messages like so

```
<% @animal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

So as a quick fix I have created a helper that just strips out the first part of the text, but this feels too hacky and I would like to know how to do it properly with Rails:

```
def error_edit(message)
  msg = message
  msg.gsub('Animal images base', ' ')
end

// View
<% @animal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= error_edit(msg) %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my controller. I know its not a better solution but I am sure it will give you an idea.

Please don't use

```
errors.add(:base, "Please add an image")
```

User this

```
errors.add(:attribute, "Please add an image")

<% @animal.errors.each do |key,value| %>
  <li><%= "#{key.to_s.titleize} #{value}".html_safe %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |animal|
    animal.errors[:base] << "Please add an image" if animal.image.size < 1
  end
end
```

I will also suggest you looking at this link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

Adds message to the error messages on attribute.

what you are doing is adding the message on an attribute called base, which is obviously not what you would like to have

update: add_to_base method was removed from rails 3. You should use errors[:base] << "error" instead.

Comment: i get an undefined method add_to_base with your answer, but ill look into the link you provided a bit more

Comment: haha, i dont know whats going on with this, still outputting same error message as in question... sure ill figure it out in time